# Is there any latest release or other option to use LVS load balancing?

Tags: linux, web-server, load-balancing, lvs

i checked the official linux virtual server website and they havent updated or discontinued since 2014.So, i cant find documentations for 4.5.X kernels. Is squid or HA proxy better alternative to LVS TUN/DR and APACHE mod_proxy? IS there any other better solution to use open source layer 4 or 7 techniques to load balance a statefull application? Not talking about DNS RR

Comment: ...please wait while we connect to your neural network!

Comment: `Is there any other better solution to use open source layer 4 or 7 techniques to load balance a statefull application?` Yes, no, maybe. Some details about what you're looking to load-balance would be handy.